# how can I save data using this program and be able to call (talk command) it later in a command

Tags: python, database, dataframe, call, storing-data

I am still 14 years old so please excuse my coding mistake I'm new to coding and I want to create a virtual assistant that can save information and that can tell me the saved information when I ask it to tell me thank you very much for your time and help.

```
from argparse import ONE_OR_MORE
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import os

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            comand=listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'google' in command:
                command = command.replace('google', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command

def run_google():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    #this is the part that I need help with ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

    #this part is to collect information and save it in a data folder
  
    elif 'save this information' in command:                              
        info = command.replace('save this information', '')        ←    
        data = open("data.py", "w")
        data.write(info)
        data.close()
        print(info)
        talk(info)
     #this part is to retrieve the previous saved data

    elif 'tell me inforamtion about' in command:
        call_info = command.replace('tell me inforamtion about', '') 
        open.data.py(#search for called info in data file)
        print(called_info)
        talk(called_info)
         
        
while True:
    run_google()
```

Comment: you are pretty decent doing this at 14 !!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) -- a way to associate some data to a name. The easiest way is by using the file system, storing each topic in a separate file.

```py
def save_info(topic: str, info: str):
    """
    Save the provided info with the specified topic name.
    If there is already a stored topic with this name, overwrite it.
    """
    with open('topics/' + topic + '.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(info)

def load_info(topic: str, msg_if_none: str = "No info for this topic") -> str:
    """
    Load the info stored for this topic name.
    If there is no such topic, return `msg_if_none`.
    """
    try:
        with open('topics/' + topic + '.txt') as file:
            return file.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return msg_if_none
```

If you want to store only a single topic, you can just use a fixed topic name:

```py
# ....
elif 'save this information' in command:
    info = command.replace('save this information', '')
    save_info("general_topic", info)
    talk("Saved info: " + info)

elif 'tell me information' in command:
    talk(load_info("general_topic"))
```

If you wanted to store more than a single topic, I would first record  which topic the user wants to store, and then the text to record there. That would look something like:

```py
def take_input():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening for text...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            text = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            text = text.lower()
            return text
    except: pass

# .......

elif command.startswith('save information about'):
    topic = command.replace('save information about', '')
    talk("What would you like to save for topic " + topic + "?")
    info = take_input()
    save_info(topic, info)
    talk("For topic " + topic + " the following is saved: " + info)

elif command.startswith('tell me about'):
    topic = command.replace('tell me about', '')
    info = load_info(topic)
    talk(info)
```

This could be enough for your project, but there are a vast number of database options. Right now your [data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model) is simply text related to topics, but you might need to store more complex data later -- for example, you might decide to keep information about people, like names, contacts, birthdates and so on. For that, I would choose a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) that keeps its data in tables; I like using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) with it, so if you're interested take a look at the [quickstart for an ORM named Peewee](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html).

Comment: Danya02 thank you for your help but can you help me integrate this to my programme please

Comment: thank you again but I'm getting an error load info and save info not defined what should I do,should I create another file in which I define these two variables and leave them empty

Comment: @yassinamr Those two functions are defined in my first code block. You can put those into your program file before you use them, for example next to where you define `talk` and `take_command`.